# Debugging Typemock test case in Visual Studio 2015 throws TypeMockException

Tags: typemock

In Visual Studio 2015, when I attempt to **debug** a test that uses Typemock (and I use the Visual Studio Test Explorer, not Typemock's SmartRunner),  on the first call to a Typemock method I get the following exception:

> **TypeMock.TypeMockException** occurred     HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=
>   *** Typemock Isolator is currently disabled. Enable using
>   the following:
>
> - Within Visual Studio:
>
>   - Use Typemock Smart Runner
>   - For other runners, Choose Typemock Menu and click "Integrate with Other Runners"
>
>     - To run Typemock Isolator as part of an automated process you can:
>     - run tests via TMockRunner.exe command line tool
>     - use 'TypeMockStart' tasks for MSBuild or NAnt

I've followed the instructions and verified that:

- Typemock is enabled
- I already have "Enable Mocking integration" checked in the settings

Also,

- The test runs properly when I choose "Run Selected Tests".  I only get the exception when I choose "Debug Selected Tests"
- Prior to Visual Studio 2015, I did not get this exception during debugging.

**Question**: What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **IntelliTrace** functionality does not work with Typemock.  **Disabling** IntelliTrace in the Visual Studio options (Options->IntelliTrace->General->Enable IntelliTrace) works around the issue.

See:

- [Typemock: Typemock Isolater is not currently enabled](http://www.typemock.com/answers/11331/typemock-isolator-is-not-currently-enabled)
- [Typemock: Debug Test on 64 bit machine](http://www.typemock.com/answers/11017/debug-test-on-64-bit-machine)
- [Typemock: On Windows 7 x64 with VS 2010](http://www.typemock.com/answers/11097/typemock-on-windows-7-x64-with-vs2010)

Comment: Disclaimer: I work at Typemock. I can confirm that Isolator's integration with IntelliTrace causes this issue. Disabling it is the workaround, we're working on supporting it, I'll update here.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock

This issue is fixed in Isolator 8.3 and will apply to all following versions.
Isolator 8.3 was released on  2.21.2016 and available for download at www.typemock.com.